# Meu userscript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um script de greasemonkey mas meu código não funciona, não sei se é o meu navegador, mas se acharem algum erro corrijam por favor.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ---
// @namespace   ---
// @description ---
// @author      ---
// @match       http://agar.io/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-play btn-primary btn-needs-server")[0].innerHTML = "Jogar";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-success btn-freecoins")[0].innerHTML = "Moedas Grátis";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-shop")[0].innerHTML = "Loja";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-warning btn-spectate btn-needs-server")[0].innerHTML = "Assistir";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-danger btn-logout")[0].innerHTML = "Desconectar";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-play-guest btn-success btn-needs-server")[0].innerHTML = "Jogar sem Conta";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-warning btn-login-play btn-needs-server")[0].innerHTML = "Conectar";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-text")[0].innerHTML = "Conectar com Facebook";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-text")[1].innerHTML = "Conectar com Google";
document.getElementsByClassName("outlined-text")[0].innerHTML = "Conectando...";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-info btn-copy-token copy-party-token")[0].innerHTML = "Copiar";
document.getElementById("create-party-btn").innerHTML = "Criar";
document.getElementById("joinPartyToken").placeholder = "Token da Party";
document.getElementById("join-party-btn").innerHTML = "Entrar";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-donate")[0].innerHTML = "Doar por clique [Anúncio]";
document.getElementById("skin").placeholder = "URL da Skin (link direto)";
document.getElementById("clantag").placeholder = "TAG";

setInterval(repeat, 500);
function repeat{
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML == "Guest"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML = "Convidado";
    }
}
```

Ele abre o agar.io com o script do szymy (Ogar.io) e traduz para o português, mas ele não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você escreveu a função errado, faltou os parentes `()`:

```
function repeat{
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML == "Guest"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML = "Convidado";
    }
}
```

O correto é:

```
function repeat() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML == "Guest"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("agario-profile-name")[0].innerHTML = "Convidado";
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu percebi isso antes de ver sua resposta, mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 0):

O problema principal é porque você está buscando elementos por várias classes de forma direta usando `document.getElementsByClassName`. Use `document.querySelector` ao invés desse método.

E ao invés de usar `setInterval` você pode usar o `requestAnimFrame` implementado no código do Agar.io (sim, está global):

```
requestAnimFrame(function repeat() {

    /* Mudanças nesse bloco */

    requestAnimFrame(repeat);

});
```

Porém não sei se atualizar o HTML do jogo com um intervalo é a maneira mais eficiente, mas o código do jogo é um pouco obfuscado e por isso é difícil de descobrir isso...

Comment: querySelector somente retorna o primeiro elemento, eu deveria usar o querySelectorAll

Comment: Mas algo mais estranho, é que eu testei o codigo no console do firefox (o código original) e funcionou, então deve ser algo a ver com o greasemonkey. Vou tentar resolver isso

Comment: `querySelectorAll` retorna uma lista (array) de elementos, enquanto `querySelector` só retorna ao mínimo um elemento. Essa é a diferença. Eu usaria o `querySelector` em um caso desses, mas pela questão de cross-browser, não usaria.